# maximum of bounded integer-valued function exists

Tags: functional-analysis, integers

is there a counterexample for the following statement?

The maximum of a bounded (from above) integer-valued function over any domain exists.

Comment: Any bounded collection of integers has a maximum.  No counter-examples exist (unless, I suppose, you consider the Bourbakist example of an integer valued function on the emptyset?).

Comment: I believe this holds for any discrete function $f$ such that there is a $d > 0$ for which $f(x) \ne f(y) \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \ge d$.